# Show if a message in the mutt index has an attachment

Tags: mutt

Is there a way to have Mutt's index show if a message has an attachment?

This would be similar to how Gmail shows a paperclip next to messages with an attachment.

I can limit the messages with attachments using `~X 1-15`, but it's nice to see whether messages have an attachment in the index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the number of attachments (`%X`) to the index format setting.

For example, this shows the number of attachments after the status flags:

```
set index_format="%4C %Z %X %{%y%m%d} %-12.12L %?M?(#%03M)&(%4c)? %?y?(%.20Y) ?%s"
```

Or, if you only want an indicator, you can use conditionals. If instead of `%X` you put `%?X?A&-?`, you'll get `A` for messages with attachments, and `-` for messages without.

Search for the chapter `Format strings` in the supplied documentation.

Comment: This works. You can also use the paperclip unicode symbol 1F4CE to get Gmail look. I use the following string `%?X?&  ?`. Either copy paste the symbol or in Vim to enter unicode symbols use `CTRL-V Shift-U 1F4CE`.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for encrypted / signed messages? I imagine something like this: `%?S?✒️&  ?` or `%?P?&  ?` but these don't work...

Comment: Weird thing is, if there is indicator or color for email with attachment, the size part(%?l?%4l&%4c?) in the index goes wrong

Answer (score 3):

To put a paper clip for an attachment, the following works for me (and also puts blanks correctly).

```
set index_format="%Z %?X?&  ? %{!%a %b%d'%y %I:%M:%S%p%Z}  %-12.12L  %?M?(#%03M)&(%4c)?  %?y?(%.20Y) ?%s"
```

I made it a bit more concise to save on screenspace...